# How to cURL in Angular 2?

Tags: angular, curl, parse-platform, angular2-http

I am using Parse REST API to fetch some data using Angular2, everything works fine but I need to fetch data with a **descending order**, back to Parse documentation the following should be done:

```
curl -X GET \
-H "X-Parse-Application-Id: appID" \
-H "X-Parse-REST-API-Key: keyID" \
-G \
--data-urlencode 'order=-score' \
https://api.parse.com/1/classes/GameScore
```

I want to simulate that cURL in my Angular2 code, what I need mainly is to implement : **data-urlencode**

Currently, here is my Angular2 code:

```
this.http.get('https://example.com/classes/GameScore').subscribe(data => {
    this.res = data.json().results;
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should look at `URLSearchParams` API which will help you to form query string. Before using it do import `URLSearchParams` from `angular2/http`

**Code**

```
import {URLSearchParams} from 'angular2/http'; //do add this line

var search = new URLSearchParams()
search.set('order', '-score');

this.http.get('https://example.com/classes/GameScore', { search }).subscribe(data => {
    this.res = data.json().results;
});
```

Comment: @JamesRunner Glad to know that. Thanks :-)